# Example of complete (quasi) normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ satisfying $\|a\|< \infty$ but $a \notin X$, $X \subset Y$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If we consider sequence of eventually zero sequences with supremem norm i.e. $(C_{00}, \| \cdot \|_{\infty})$, then taking $a=(1,1,1,...)$, we see it does not belong to space even if its supremem norm is finite. Does there exist any complete space where a similar situation can occur?

Comment: You are asking a variant of “does there exist a set for which an element lies outside of it?“. The question is not well formed.

Comment: From the example that i provided while writing the question, i guess question should be clear.  The question is: is it possible to have completeness if such a case occurs.

Comment: How do you define $\lVert a\rVert$ when $a\notin X$?

Comment: Is "Does there exist a normed space $(Y, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Y)$ and a subspace $X \subseteq Y$ s.t. $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Y)$ is complete but there exists a $y \in Y \setminus X$?" a correct reformulation of your question?

Comment: Assuming that the reformulation given by @G.Chiusole is correct you can take a complete normed space $(Y,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ and any closed proper subspace $X\subsetneq Y$, right?

Comment: Yes. It is correct reformulation. Thank you.